# How to add a property to all fabricjs objects?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to use additional properties on the shape objects like circle, polygon, line, box,... and instead of adding them each manually on the object itself, I would then like to add them globally to all objects.

I've looked through some other SO answers, but these were always to a single specific object and not all objects (or all shape objects).

Anyone knows if this is even achievable and if yes, how?

Comment: Something like `canvas.getObjects().forEach( (obj) => { obj.set("field", value); } )`?  You could also add a `filter` in there if you only want a specific kind of object.

Comment: That is my current implementation, but I want something solid that sets them globally and forget about them.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in your code.

```
fabric.Object.prototype.set("field", "value"); 

// field: the property you want to set for all types of objects
// value: the value you want to set that field for all types of objects
```

You can access this property in other objects. e.g., Rect, Circle, Image...

```
fabric.Object.prototype.Rect.field
// It returns "value"
```

Comment: Have not tested it yet, but will accept it as soon as I am back at it again, thanks for the answer!